# What is this VPN setting good for?

Tags: wi-fi, vpn

I have a Huawei U8160 (also known as Vodafone 858 Smart) which is running CyanogenMod7.2

There are settings for VPN which are empty. I was wondering if the VPN server setting should be set to a real server?

Or should I just not touch it?

Comment: Enter your server's detail.

Comment: i don't know i'm asking

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking here. It sounds like you may need to simply read some tutorials/documentation about how VPNs work or how to set one up for yourself. That's a bit out-of-scope for this site, if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: i've a simple question : does vpn server must be a real one?

Comment: What would be the counterpart to a *real* VPN server be?

Comment: I think you stumbled upon the VPN settings and just want to know what it is?

Comment: If I'm right here, maybe this question should be edited  to ask 'What are those VPN settings good for?'. Wouldn't that be a legitimate question some unaware (of VPN) users might ask?

Comment: @ce4: Sure, I'd think that "What are the VPN settings for?" is a perfectly fine question. OP: I'm still not clear on what you're asking. As Flow noted, what would be the alternative to a "real" VPN server? What would you enter into those settings otherwise? Do you actually need to set up a VPN or are you simply asking what those settings do? Please try to clarify.

Comment: Its not an Android issue.. So, I am voting to close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A VPN is a virtual private network.

Your device connects to a VPN server through a public connection and tunnels a second *virtual* and *private* (to you) connection through the VPN server to see all devices that are protected behind the VPN server (such as a company's whole network infrastructure for example).

This feature is mostly used for road warriors that want to connect to a company's internal network resources like email / internal web sites and so on. Other uses are: Securely connect two different company sites virtually, working from a home office...

It's generally not for normal users (Cyanogenmod includes it for some power users that also connect to a VPN).

See [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Private_Network) for more.

Regarding your question: Leave the setting empty, you just don't need it most probably.